# error in join command and sorting in linux

Tags: linux, sorting, join

I have 2 files

file 1

```
1 1:712591 NA 712591 T G NA
1 1:733687 NA 733687 G A NA
1 1:739347  NA 739347 G C NA
1 1:739565  NA 739565 C G NA
```

file 2

```
1 712591 rs2345678
1  739347 rs12456789
1  739565 rs8523694
1 733687 rs74158260
```

I sorted both files with respective 4th column in `file 1` and 2nd column in `file 2`

I tried to match two files with matching columns using `join` command :

```
join -1 4 -2 2 file1 file2 | head

join: file1.txt:4: is not sorted: 1 1:739347  NA 739347 G C NA
join: file2.txt:2: is not sorted: 1  739347 rs12456789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, you are using the correct files?
I get the expected output:

```
% cat file1
1 1:712591 NA 712591 T G NA
1 1:733687 NA 733687 G A NA
1 1:739347  NA 739347 G C NA
1 1:739565  NA 739565 C G NA
% cat file2
1 712591 rs2345678
1  739347 rs12456789
1  739565 rs8523694
1 733687 rs74158260
```

File 2 is not sorted, I get the error

```
% join -1 4 -2 2 file1 file2 | head   
join: file2:4: is not sorted: 1 733687 rs74158260
712591 1 1:712591 NA T G NA 1 rs2345678
739347 1 1:739347 NA G C NA 1 rs12456789
739565 1 1:739565 NA C G NA 1 rs8523694
```

I sort both files:

```
% sort -k4 file1 > file1.s
% sort -k2 file2 > file2.s
```

Now they are sorted:

```
% cat file1.s
1 1:712591 NA 712591 T G NA
1 1:733687 NA 733687 G A NA
1 1:739347  NA 739347 G C NA
1 1:739565  NA 739565 C G NA
% cat file2.s 
1 712591 rs2345678
1 733687 rs74158260
1  739347 rs12456789
1  739565 rs8523694
```

And the join works:

```
% join -1 4 -2 2 file1.s file2.s | head
712591 1 1:712591 NA T G NA 1 rs2345678
733687 1 1:733687 NA G A NA 1 rs74158260
739347 1 1:739347 NA G C NA 1 rs12456789
739565 1 1:739565 NA C G NA 1 rs8523694
```

Comment: i get  them perfectly but repeats same sort error in another line in same file

Comment: @Matrix_32 afaik, `join` does not compare "numeric", but "stringy". So do **NOT** use `-n` on `sort`. (referring to the screenshot you deleted)

Comment: I have 1000+rows in each **file1** and **file2**                                                               
same **error** in different line results as below :                                                              
 `$sort -k4 file1 > file1.s`                                                                                                   `$sort -k2 file2 > file2.s` `join -1 4 -2 2 file1.s file2.s | head`
`$join: file1.s:2796: is not **sorted** : 1 10035688 rs1195640784`                                       `$join: file2.s:1143: is not **sorted** : 1 1:1026919 NA 1026919 A G`

Comment: did you check if your files are sorted manually? Open them in an editor and go to the lines and check if they are sorted. A number starting with `1` should be close to the top of the file, even if it a large number: `echo -e "123\n2\n11111" | sort -- 11111 - 123 - 2`